# Relative Root with Visual Studio ASP.NET debugger

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an ASP.NET project which is physically located at C:\Projects\MyStuff\WebSite2. When I run the app with the Visual Studio debugger it seems that the built in web server considers "C:\Projects\MyStuff\" to be the relative root, not "C:\Projects\MyStuff\WebSite2". Is there a web.config setting or something that will allow tags like `<img src='/img/logo.png' />` to render correctly without having to resort to the ASP.NET specific tags like `<asp:image />`? If I code for the debugger's peculiarities then when I upload to the production IIS server everthing is off.

How do you resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this trick that Scott Guthrie posted on his blog http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/19/tip-trick-how-to-run-a-root-site-with-the-local-web-server-using-vs-2005-sp1.aspx

to cut to the fix: select your project/solution in solution explorer and then open the Properties tab like you would if you were editing a textbox. If you right click and go to "Property Pages" that is the wrong place.